# Machine Learning - Classification Problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, text-classification

Is there any command to call mis-classified values while predicting any values in a model in-short the ones which have been classified inaccurately.

Comment: This needs way more details... However, it loooks like you can just index on  `y_pred`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method in the scikit-learn API. You can however write it yourself in a few lines:

```py
import numpy as np

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = ...  # some dataset
model = ...  # some scikit learn model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# command to get misclassified examples assuming you have numpy arrays
X_test[np.argwhere(y_pred != y_test)]
```